# Simple jQuery nth-child query - animations not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, css-selectors

I won't post my whole script because it's most likely irrelevant and will save wasting time.

Why does the following code work:

```
if (rand === 0)
        {
            $('#idOfElementInsideContainer')
            .animate({padding: ap, background : ab}, {duration:ad})
        }
```

and this not:

```
if (rand === 0)
        {
            $('#container:nth-child(1)')
            .animate({padding: ap, background : ab}, {duration:ad})
        }
```

I've put an alert after the animate line just to prove to myself that it is actually going inside if statement.

Comment: You should post the HTML for the container and its children.  Perhaps the element you are targeting is not actually the first child?  Note that nth-child is a 1-based list, meaning item 1 is the first item (there is no item 0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$('#container').children().eq(1)
        .animate({padding: ap, background : ab}, {duration:ad})
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you. I did try that but forgot to add the .children()

Comment: @Luke i was happy to help ^_^